# How have you successfully implemented MessageBox.Show() functionality in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, triggers, messagebox

I've got a WPF application **which calls MessageBox.Show() way back in the ViewModel** (to check if the user really wants to delete). *This actually works*, but **goes against the grain of MVVM** since the ViewModel should not explicitly determine what happens on the View.

So now I am thinking **how can I best implement the MessageBox.Show() functionality** in my MVVM application, options:

1. I could have a message with the text "Are you sure...?" along with two buttons Yes and No all in a Border in my XAML, and create a trigger on the template so that it is collapsed/visible based on a ViewModelProperty called **AreYourSureDialogueBoxIsVisible**, and then when I need this dialogue box, assign AreYourSureDialogueBoxIsVisible to "true", and also handle the two buttons via DelegateCommand back in my ViewModel.
2. I could also somehow try to handle this with triggers in XAML so that the Delete button actually just makes some Border element appear with the message and buttons in it, and the Yes button did the actually deleting.

**Both solutions seem to be too complex** for what used to be a couple lines of code with MessageBox.Show().

**In what ways have you successfully implemented Dialogue Boxes in your MVVM applications?**

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315180/model-view-presenter-and-modal-dialog-boxes-how-to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of the two you mention, I prefer option #2.  The Delete button on the page just makes the "Confirm Delete Dialog" appear.  The "Confirm Delete Dialog" actually kicks off the Delete.

Have you checked out Karl Shifflett's [WPF Line Of Business Slides and Demos](https://web.archive.org/web/20150619163502/https://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/chicago-wpf-lob-tour-materials-new-materials-added/)?  I know he does something like this.  I'll try to remember where.

EDIT: Check out Demo #11 "Data Validation in MVVM" (EditContactItemsControlSelectionViewModel.DeleteCommand). Karl calls a popup from the ViewModal (What!? :-). I actually like your idea better. Seems easier to Unit Test.

Comment: I finally solved this with solution #1. It doesn't pop up a window, just "inserts" a Border element at the top of the screen by triggering it from Visibility=collapsed to Visibility=Visible. I created the DelegateCommands: TurnOnDialogueBoxDelete, DeleteItem and CancelDialogueBoxDelete. I created the ViewModelProperties: DialogueBoxDeleteStatus, ItemIdMarkedForDeletion, and DialogueBoxDeleteText. So it is not as easy as a simple MessageBox.Show() but it works nicely. I'm sure eventually some of this can be abstracted away for when other dialogue boxes are needed.

Comment: if (System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Are you need to delete?", "", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                // Do your action
            }

Answer (score 13):

Services to the rescue. Using [Onyx](http://wpfonyx.codeplex.com) (disclaimer, I'm the author) this is as easy as:

```
public void Foo()
{
    IDisplayMessage dm = this.View.GetService<IDisplayMessage>();
    dm.Show("Hello, world!");
}
```

In a running application, this will indirectly call MessageBox.Show("Hello, world!"). When testing, the IDisplayMessage service can be mocked and provided to the ViewModel to do what ever you want to accomplish during the test.

Comment: I am wondering if indirectly accessing View is still considered following MVVM practice.

Comment: It never was by most, but I simply disagree. There's no tight coupling here, so I'd challenge someone to show *why* there's a design issue here. What is an anti-pattern in the above example is the use of service locator instead of dependency injection. Regardless, the IDisplayMessage concept, the real answer here, doesn't depend on either service locator or indirectly accessing a View.

Answer (score 5):

I just create an interface (IMessageDisplay or similar) which gets injected into the VM, and it has methods like a MessageBox (ShowMessage() etc).  You can implement that using a standard messagebox, or something more WPF specific (I use [this one on CodePlex](http://prajeeshprathap.codeplex.com/SourceControl/PatchList.aspx) by Prajeesh).

That way everything's separated and testable.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Dean Chalk's answer now that his link is kaput:

In the App.xaml.cs file we hook up the confirm dialog to the viewmodel.

```cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    var confirm = (Func<string, string, bool>)((msg, capt) => MessageBox.Show(msg, capt, MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes);
    var window = new MainWindowView();
    var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(confirm);
    window.DataContext = viewModel;
    ...
}
```

In the view (MainWindowView.xaml) we have a button that calls a command in the ViewModel

```html
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand}" />
```

The viewmodel (MainWindowViewModel.cs) uses a delegate command to show the "Are you sure?" dialog and perform the action. In this example it is a `SimpleCommand` similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346493/345659), but any implementation of ICommand should do.

```cs
private readonly Func<string, string, bool> _confirm;

//constructor
public MainWindowViewModel(Func<string, string, bool> confirm)
{
    _confirm = confirm;
    ...
}

#region Delete Command
private SimpleCommand _deleteCommand;
public ICommand DeleteCommand
{
    get { return _deleteCommand ?? (_deleteCommand = new SimpleCommand(ExecuteDeleteCommand, CanExecuteDeleteCommand)); }
}

public bool CanExecuteDeleteCommand()
{
    //put your logic here whether to allow deletes
    return true;
}

public void ExecuteDeleteCommand()
{
    bool doDelete =_confirm("Are you sure?", "Confirm Delete");
    if (doDelete)
    {
        //delete from database
        ...
    }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 3):

What about raising an Event like `"MessageBoxRequested"` handled in the codebehind of the View (anyway it's View only code so I don't see any problem with having this code on the codebehind).

Comment: True, MVVM is for me connecting the model and the view. But the view should behave on himself too.

Answer (score 3):

*Just in case anyone else is still reading and unsatisfied:*

I just wanted to handle 'notification' type MessageBoxes (i.e. I don't care about the `DialogResult`), but the problem that I have with most solutions I've read about is that they seem to indirectly force you to choose your View implementation (that is, currently I have a `MessageBox.Show`, but if I later decide to just fiddle with the visibility of a hidden panel directly in my View, that won't mesh very nicely with an `INotification` interface passed in to the ViewModel).

So I went for quick and dirty:

The ViewModel has a `string NotificationMessage` property, with changes notified to `PropertyChanged`.

The View subscribes to `PropertyChanged`, and if it sees the `NotificationMessage` property come through, does whatever it wants.

OK, so this means the View has code-behind, and the name of `PropertyChanged` is hard-coded, but it would be hard-coded in the XAML anyway. And it means I avoid all the stuff like converters for Visibility, and properties to say whether the notification is still visible or not.

(Admittedly this is just for a limited use-case (fire and forget), I haven't given much thought to how I might want to extend it.)

Answer (score 2):

There is so many answers on this topic that vary from creating a custom class to using third party libraries. I would say use a third party library if you want cool pop ups with nice visuals.

But if you just want to use the regular message box from microsoft for your WPF app here is an MVVM/unit test friendly implementation:

Initially I thought I would just inherit from message box and wrap it with an interface but I couldn't due to Message box not having a public constructor, so here is the "easy" solution:

Decompiling Message box in visual studio you can see all the method overloads, I checked which ones I wanted then created a new class and added the methods, wrapped it with an interface and ta-da! Now you can use ninject to bind the interface and class, inject it and use Moq to unit test e.t.c.

Create an interface (only added a few of the overloads as I don't need them all):

```
public interface IMessageBox
    {
        /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message, title bar caption, and button; and that returns a result.</summary>          
        MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button);

        /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message, title bar caption, button, and icon; and that returns a result.</summary>           
        MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon);

        /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message and title bar caption; and that returns a result.</summary>            
        MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption);
    }
```

Then we have the class that will inherit from it:

```
public class MessageBoxHelper : IMessageBox
    {
        /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message, title bar caption, button, and icon; and that returns a result.</summary>            
        public MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button,
            MessageBoxImage icon)
        {
            return MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, icon, MessageBoxResult.None,
                MessageBoxOptions.None);
        }

        /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message, title bar caption, and button; and that returns a result.</summary>            
        public MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, MessageBoxButton button)
        {
            return MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button, MessageBoxImage.None, MessageBoxResult.None,
                MessageBoxOptions.None);
        }

        /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message and title bar caption; and that returns a result.</summary>            
        public MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption)
        {
            return MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.None,
                MessageBoxResult.None, MessageBoxOptions.None);
        }

        /// <summary>Displays a message box that has a message and that returns a result.</summary>           
        public MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText)
        {
            return MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, string.Empty, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.None,
                MessageBoxResult.None, MessageBoxOptions.None);
        }
    }
```

Now just use this when injecting e.t.c and boom u have a flimsy abstraction that will do the trick... which is fine depending on where you will use it. My case is a simple app only meant to do a few things, so no point over engineering a solution. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a simple MessageBox wrapper control for us to use in pure MVVM solution and still allowing unit testing capability. The details are in my blog [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20191003012738/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/mukapu/archive/2010/03/12/user-prompts-messagebox-with-mvvm.aspx)

mukapu

Comment: The solution in the link is broken can you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

WPF & Silverlight MessageBoxes

MVVM supported

http://slwpfmessagebox.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would just throw it from the VM. I dont want to have to use someone else's service or write my own just to throw a messagebox.

Comment: Yeah but if you're testing your view model in a unit test, what's going to happen ? Does your test will block waiting for user to click on 'yes' or 'no' ?

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem where I had to replace the MessageBox.Show in the ViewModels with some fully MVVM complaint message box mechanism.

To achieve this I used `InteractionRequest<Notification>` and `InteractionRequest<Confirmation>` along with interaction triggers and wrote my own Views for the message box.

What I've implemented is published [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/812542/MessageBox-using-MVVM-Patterns)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is not by putting a service or the like that handles the MessageBox on the view model. It still violates MVVM, as the view model still handles the displaying of MessageBox indirectly. The view model should know nothing about the view and focus on managing data. And it's the responsibility of the View to manage the displaying of a view component.

So you have to make the view observe the view model, and then do the UI logic on the view based on the observation. One way to achieve that is by listening to the ViewModel's event and show the MessageBox based on the argument of the event.

This is just one example on showing how you can achieve this, and you can customize and leverage it for your own need and purpose:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MessageBoxMVVMExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MessageBoxMVVMExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Input}"/>
        <Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private BaseViewModel _viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = _viewModel;
        _viewModel.NewMessageDialog += OnNewMessageDialog;
    }

    private void OnNewMessageDialog(MessageDialogEventArgs args)
    {
        // you can also put it on a service to achieve decoupling

        MessageBox.Show(args.Message, args.MessageType.ToString());
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _input = String.Empty;
    public string Input
    {
        get => _input;
        set
        {
            _input = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new(nameof(Input)));
        }
    }
    public RelayCommand SubmitCommand => new(o => ValidateNumeric());

    public void ValidateNumeric()
    {
        decimal dec;

        if (decimal.TryParse(Input, out dec))
        {
            OnNewMessageDialog(new(MessageType.SUCCESS, "Yes, it's a valid number!"));
        }

        else
        {
            OnNewMessageDialog(new(MessageType.ERROR, "No, it's an invalid number!"));
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseViewModel.cs**

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public event MessageDialogEventHandler? NewMessageDialog;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    protected void OnNewMessageDialog(MessageDialogEventArgs args)
    {
        NewMessageDialog?.Invoke(args);
    }
}

public enum MessageType {
   INFO,
   ERROR,
   WARNING,
   SUCCESS
}

public class MessageDialogEventArgs
{ 
    public MessageType MessageType { get; set; } = MessageType.INFO;
    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public MessageDialogEventArgs(MessageType messageType, string message)
    {
        MessageType = messageType;
        Message = message;
    }

}

public delegate void MessageDialogEventHandler(MessageDialogEventArgs messageDialogEventArgs);
```

**RelayCommand.cs**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _callback;
    private Func<object, bool>? _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> callback, Func<object, bool>? canExecute)
    {
        this._callback = callback;
        this._canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> callback) : this(callback, null) { }

    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
    {
        return this._canExecute == null || this._canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        this._callback(parameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Working fine [MVVM]

```
if (System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Are you need to delete?", "", 
   System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    // Do your action
}
```

Comment: how that's MVVM?