# Display a message box in MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, dialog, mvvm-light

I want to display a message box with a message and a OK button. Implementing dialog box doesnot seems to be straight forward. Could help me to sort this out with a simple solution?

I got this link but source code is not available now

[how to show Messagebox in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705991/how-to-show-messagebox-in-mvvm)

[Handling Dialogs in WPF with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454868/handling-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Dialogs in WPF with MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454868/handling-dialogs-in-wpf-with-mvvm)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14297637/442444

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF MessageBox with MVVM pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297312/wpf-messagebox-with-mvvm-pattern)