# Bind Window object to viewmodel property from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have viewmodel like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IView View { get; set; }
}
```

And Window that implements `IView`.

I need to bind this exact Window to `view` property without changing `ViewModel` class.

Is this possible to do with only XAML of that Window?

I can do it this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47266732/3206223

But would have to change `ViewModel` which is undesirable in this case.

Comment: How do you set the DataContext property of the window?

Comment: Basically: `window.DataContext = New ViewModel(properties);`. And then: `window.ShowDialog();`.

Comment: This part might be changed if required.

Comment: So how about just setting the View property of the view model? `window.DataContext = new ViewModel(properties) { View = window };`

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the ViewModel in XAML and set it as DataContext:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.AppWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels">
      <Window.DataContext>
           <local:ViewModel/>
      </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

Edit:

Change

```
window.DataContext = new ViewModel(properties);
window.ShowDialog();
```

to

```
var vm = new ViewModel(properties);
vm.View = window;
window.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I already bound ViewModel to DataContext (in other way but still). Now I need to bind this Window itself to ViewModel.View.

Comment: @InfernumDeus you just need to add the property View to your path like <Label Content="{Binding View.Text}" /> where Text ist the public property in IView you want to bind to for example

Comment: The problem is I already know how to bind _data_ from IView. I need to bind this `<Window ...>` object to be able to access IView inside of VIewModel.

Comment: To make it clear I need Window object inside my `public IView View` property.

Comment: Okay, got it now. Where do you instantiate your ViewModel? Is there any possibility to pass your Window instance?

Comment: Yes. As I stated in my question I can do that. But in this case I will have to change ViewModel's code which should be avoided if possible.

Comment: You don't need to change the ViewModels code itself, just the code where you set the DataContext of the Window... So again: Where do you instantiate the ViewModel object / where you set the DataContext?

Comment: Oh... Now I get it. Thank you!