# Select All in DataGrid from button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a little problem about selecting all rows from a DataGrid.
The question is that the CommandButton is in a UserControl which refers to the MainViewModel and the grid is in a UserControl which refers to another ViewModel. The first thought was to make a static method and call it from the mvm, but the datagrid is not static and can't be called. How can i do?

Edit:

I actually solved the problem by rferencing a static instance of the grid from the code behind.

In the pushbutton viewmodel i recalled the select all method inside the command execution

```
 if (_CommandBtnSelectAll == null)
 {
    // creo una nuova istanza del comando
    _CommandBtnSelectAll = new USCommands(
       item =>
       {
             ViewControlCodeBehind.grid.SelectAll();
       }
 }
```

In the ViewControl Code Behind i just had to set a static instance of a new DataGrid and assign it the actual datagrid.

```
public static DataGrid grid;

public ControlBody() // It's the UserControl initialization
{
   this.grid = DataGridControl; // DataGridControl is the name of the actual control
}
```

Comment: Marco: please add relevant code to your post so we can see how your xaml is structured. There's a very right chance that you can simply exploit the inherited DataContext of usercontrol & pass it into command as a CommandParameter that can then set a property on ViewModel (For example `foreach(var item in viewModel.Items) item.IsSelected = true;` This will then get automatically picked up by DataGrid (assuming ViewModel.Items was bound to DataGrid & IsSelected was bound to ItemContainer.IsSelected) You can do a search on SO for IsSelected binding if you need more info on how to bind it.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a message or an event from the view model and subscribe to and handle this event in the view using a messenger or an event aggregator. Please refer to [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) blog post for more information about this.

The other option would be to inject the view model with an interface that the view implements as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266184/getting-window-from-view-model/47266732#47266732).