# Xamarin Forms: Display Alerts after firing command in ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

In a ViewModel I have a Command, and in a View I have a button binded to that Command :

```
...
public Command SaveCommand { get;  }

private async void Save(){
  IsBusy = true;
            Estatus = "Grabando...";
            Task<bool> taskSaved = _negotiationRepo.SaveNegotiation(_negotiation, _following);
            bool Saved = await taskSaved;
            IsBusy = false;
            if (Saved)
            {
                Estatus = "Saved";
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Negotiation","Saved correctly","OK");
            }
            else
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Negotiation", "Problem saving negotiation", "OK");
            }
}

public NegotiationVM(Client client){
...
  SaveCommand = new Command((Save),canExecute: ()=>!IsBusy);
...
}
```

In XAML View:

```
<Button Text="Save" BackgroundColor="#3276b1"  TextColor="White" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}">
```

As you can see, I have a DisplayAlert in this ViewModel class. I'm not sure, but according to MVVM I shouldn't do this here, or at least not in that way.
How can I properly display an alert or prompt after this command is fired?

I'm not using any MVVM Framework at this moment, most examples are focused in MVVM Light or Prism.

Comment: Sort of related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297312/wpf-messagebox-with-mvvm-pattern

Comment: Not sort-of-related, it's absolutely how you should handle this type of thing in MVVM, with a good code sample.

Comment: @Will Why is marked as duplicate? This is for Xamarin.Forms not WPF. Even if is similar, not equal functions and implementations.

Comment: I don't know xamarin, so I don't know if they have a built-in mechanism for this, so reopened.  If they *don't*, that dupe has your answer.  Nothing about xamarin prevents you from defining an interface to model interactions with a dialog, then implement that in your UI and pass the implementation into your view model.