# Why is TextElement.FontSize an attached property in StackPanel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am reading [WPF 4 Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331195) and I am obviously new to WPF (and C# & .NET in general)

In the book, found the following snipped of code:

```
<StackPanel TextElement.FontSize="30" TextElement.FontStyle="Italic"
            Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
   <Button MinWidth="75" Margin="10">Help</Button>
   <Button MinWidth="75" Margin="10">OK</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

`TextElement.FontSize` is an attached property. I don't understand why is it attached property ? 
(Though, I do understand the concept of dependency property)

In `Attached Properties Overview` on MS site, there is another snipped of code.

```
<DockPanel>
  <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Top">Hello</CheckBox>
</DockPanel>
```

In this case, it makes sense as to why `DockPanel.Dock` is an attached property - `DockPanel` class contains dependency property `DockProperty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're new to C#, I strongly suggest you start by doing some `Hello, World!` type of stuff in console applications before trying to get into complex WPF GUI stuff.

WPF is a complex framework not really suitable for the unexperienced. You must have a strong background in C# and OOP in general in order to learn MVVM, which is what you must learn in order to use WPF properly.

That said, `StackPanel` does not have a `FontSize` property because it's a `Panel` and not a `Control`, which is where the `FontXXX` properties are defined. That's why you can optionally define the `TextElement.FontSize` Attached Property, which are child controls will inherit due to `Dependency Property Value Inheritance` in the Visual Tree.

As an aside, that book was in a former coworker's desk, so I grabbed it and rapidly browsed thru it. I didn't find a single mention to MVVM, which at this point I consider a fundamental part of the WPF learning curve.

Comment: I read this book `WPF 4 Unleashed. Adam Nathan`, and also did not find any mention of MVVM. That way the book just a set of basic information about the WPF, which will start in the study of this technology, but unfortunately did not really learn how to create a serious application.

Comment: The buzzword-based opinions like this is what makes WPF appear complex and frightening to many of the beginners. Also, to grasp even more wisdom of MVVM, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098023/how-have-you-successfully-implemented-messagebox-show-functionality-in-mvvm

Comment: I wish the book mentioned that TextElement is a helper class that can be used to control text appearance. WPF is complex framework, but what is simple nowadays ?

Comment: More on `TextElement` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970786(v=vs.110).aspx)